# Animate deleteSections() of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that uses a flow layout. It has two sections. Based on some user input, I move cells from the first section to the second. To animate this change I use the following code:

```
let oldIndexPath = self.indexPathForAsset(asset)

self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

    //change data source

    let newIndexPath = self.indexPathForAsset(asset)
    self.collectionView.moveItem(at: oldIndexPath, to: newIndexPath)

    if self.numberOfCollectionViewSections() == 1 {
        self.collectionView.deleteSections([0])
    }
}, completion: nil)
```

the cells animate fine from the first second to the second, except for the last one. When the last cell is moved, I delete the section, and `deleteSections` is not animated. Also, if I pass a completion block to `performBatchUpdates`, it is not called.

**How can I animate the move of the last cell to the second section and the deletion of the first section?**

Comment: Hi, I notice that u did mention completion block is not called. I also notice that happens (completion block not called), especially when we perform section relation operation, in `performBatchUpdates`. I was wondering, have u figure out a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 4) {
             self.collectionView.moveItem(at: oldIndexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        }
```

try doing this